# Drop log line containing hash character

Tags: regex, logging, logstash, logstash-grok

In my Logstash shipper I want to filter out lines commented with the hash character:

```
#This log row should be dropped.
But one this should not.
```

I was able to use `grep` filter, but as it is discouraged (going to be decommissioned), I'm trying to get a `grok` filter to do it instead. This filter is not working:

```
grok {
  match => ["message", "^#.*"]
  drop_if_match => true
}
```

I also tried placing the regex in a custom pattern file, but didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Even simpler, if you're interested:

```
filter {
    if ([message] =~ /^#/) {
        drop{}
    }
}
```

The last few versions of Logstash have been putting more emphasis on branching logic [directly in the config files](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals). Takes a little getting used to, but pretty handy once you do.

Comment: You don't need extra () around the if condition. if [message =~ "^#"] { is now sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is that there is a bug in `drop_if_match=>true` (Logstash v1.2.2). Use this type of workaround:

```
grok {
  ...
  add_tag => ["some_comment"]
}
if "some_comment" in [tags] {
  drop {}
}
```