# How to drop event with logstash filter

Tags: logstash

I want drop logfile mean shoudn't export to elasticsearch, like if any log message contains "monitoring" keyword i want to drop that event. can any anyone suggest me how to do that ?

```
filter {
  if [loglevel] == "debug" {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

The above example will drop the event when loglevel debug, but drop event when log message contains "monitoring" keyword?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop log line containing hash character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215575/drop-log-line-containing-hash-character)

Comment: There's already an answer to that question. There's the relevant part in the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is

```
filter {
  if "monitoring" in [message] {
    drop { }
  }
}
```